# Replace NULL string pattern with blank

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a pipe delimiter file in which i need to replace NULL string with blank.
file is very huge around 9 GB and contain 2 million records and has 150 columns delimited by pipe.

```
PQR|NULL|NULL|NULL ABC|ABC NULL XYZ|XYZ NULL|NULL
```

**Desired output**

```
PQR|||NULL ABC|ABC NULL XYZ|XYZ NULL|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `perl` you can use lookaheads for this:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\|)NULL(?=\||$)//g' file
```

**Output:**

```
PQR|||NULL ABC|ABC NULL XYZ|XYZ NULL|
```

If you don't have `perl` then this `sed` should also work:

```
sed 's/|NULL|/||/g; s/|NULL\(|\|$\)/|\1/g' file
```

**Output:**

```
PQR|||NULL ABC|ABC NULL XYZ|XYZ NULL|
```